# subscr_payment & subscr_failed

Tags: paypal-ipn

Sorry new to all this so hopefully not stupid questions

If you use the "subscr_payment" & "subscr_failed" IPN variables what values do you get sent?
If a user starts a transaction but then cancels does an IPN get sent?

Thanks
John

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/

This tells you what data you receive with Instant Payment Notifications. Search for subscr_payment and subscr_failed to find what you get with them. There is also a description of what each data holds.